# One wants to determine $1/(2+\sqrt 3)^4$ having access to an approximate value of $\sqrt 3$.

Tags: computational-mathematics, floating-point

Can someone help me with this question please:

One wants to determine $1/(2+\sqrt 3)^4$ having access to an approximate value of $\sqrt 3$. Compare the relative errors on direct computation and on using the equivalent expression $97 - 56\sqrt 3$.

```
---|---|--|--|-|-|-|-|||||--|--|||||-|-|-|-|--|--|--|---------------
-4    -3    -2      -1      0      1       2     3     4
```

Tick marks indicates all 25 numbers in floating-point system having $\beta=2, p=3, L = -1$, and $U = 1$

> OFL = $(1.11)$<sub>2</sub> = $2^1 = (3.5)$<sub>10</sub>
>
> UFL = $(1.00)$<sub>2</sub> = ${2^-}^1 = (0.5)$<sub>10</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You should as a first step compute the actual values for some approximations. Then try theoretical reasons for the difference against them

```
ar3         1/(2+ar3)**4    97-56*ar3     1/(97+56*ar3)
================================================
1.73      0.00516612217572  0.12         0.00515782958531
1.732     0.00515505685776  0.008        0.00515485174646
1.7321    0.00515450436992  0.0024       0.00515470294478
1.73205   0.00515478060459  0.0052       0.00515477734455
```